# Python 3 Django Rest Framework - Manager object has no attribute error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to combine a filter on a custom property with a filter on a relationship in a custom manager, but keep running into the same error.

My custom EnrollmentManager says object has no attribute "end_date":

```
class EnrollmentManager(models.Manager):
  def org_students_enrolled(self, organisation):
    return self.filter(student__organisation__name=organisation).filter(self.end_date.date() >= datetime.date.today())

class Enrollment(TimeStampedModel):
  objects = EnrollmentManager()
  course = models.ForeignKey(to=Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=False)
  student = models.ForeignKey(to=Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=False)
  enrolled = models.DateTimeField()
  last_booking = models.DateTimeField()
  credits_total = models.SmallIntegerField(default=10)
  credits_balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

  @property
  def end_date(self):
    return self.enrolled + datetime.timedelta(days=182)
```

`end_date` is a custom property on `Enrollment`.

How can I use it in my manager to further filter the enrollments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model properties cannot be used to filter a queryset because those values (the `end_date`s) *do not* exist in the database, but instead they are derived from the data that is in the database (namely `enrolled`). In order to achieve this you'll have to write your filter to use the data in the model fields like so:

```py
class EnrollmentManager(models.Manager):
  def org_students_enrolled(self, organisation):
    return self.filter(student__organisation__name=organisation).filter(enrolled__gte=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=182))
```

Comment: thank you for the quick answer and for including both the explanation AND the working code! :)